# How to find specific errors using jslint and violation plugins in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jslint

My requirement is that to check for a specific error is existing on javascript file or not, if it exists makes the job fail otherwise build it successfully.

How can I check for a specific error in JavaScript file excluding other errors ( unwanted errors ) using JSLint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of `JSLint` into `grep` and search for a specific error message, and then pipe that into `wc -l` counting lines.

If the output of that is greater than 0, then `JSLint` has encountered the errors you need, otherwise it hasn't.